# Intraweb VCL for the web application not starting and StartCheck?IW_AjaxID elements appearing in Network tab

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, intraweb

When accessing from browser to one Intraweb (Delphi's VCL for the web) application I wrote, from time to time and in different browsers the app does not display properly, nothing happens on screen (the browser displays
a white page) and in the Network tab of the browser developer tools I see

[image: network tab screenshot]

In my PC for example it happens in chrome with my chrome user, but if I incognito it works normally and I see nothing in the Network tab, in other pcs it happens in firefox only.

What should I check for? I tried to search for `StartCheck?IW_AjaxID` but with no result.

Could you please suggest what causes this behavior?

Thanks!